# Excel average of values in time values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these values, which are time values. However, they are not formatted to time values, so an average will give me 8:82, when it should give 9:03. I can't seem to change the format into hh:mm, the values change to 00:00.

Current format is `#0:\00`

```
8:53    9:11
```

How do I get these recognized as time values?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `8:53` is in `A1` and `9:11` is in `B1` then you can use this formula:

`=TEXT(AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(A1),TIMEVALUE(B1)),"hh:mm")`

Which actually gives an average of `9:02`.

The Office [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645) says:

> Returns the decimal number of the time represented by a text string. The decimal number is a value ranging from 0 (zero) to 0.99988426, representing the times from 0:00:00 (12:00:00 AM) to 23:59:59 (11:59:59 P.M.).

So you wouldn't  be able to do something like `=TEXT(AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(A1:D1)),"hh:mm")`

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do it across a range, would this work? `=TEXT(AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(A1:D1)),"hh:mm")`

Comment: No, `TIMEVALUE` takes a single argument - see the edit.

Comment: @wazzahenry You can use it on a range as a *CSE formula*.